# Can not compile this Image Rotation code

Tags: c++, opencv

```
// rotate the image
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
int dx,dy,s; 
double thetaDegree;
double thetaRadian;

//for rotation
IplImage *Rotation;
Rotation = cvCloneImage(frame);
Rotation->origin = frame->origin;
CvZero(Rotation);

//get the rotation degree

thetaRadian = atan(s);      // **the s I have algorithm to do the calculation **
thetaDegree = thetaRadian *(180 / PI);

CvMat *rot = cvgetRotationMatrix2D(center, thetaDegree, 1.0);
cvWarpAffine(frame, Rotation, rot,sizeof(frame));

cvNameWindow("Rotation",1);
cvShowImage("Rotation",Rotation);
cvReleaseImage(&Rotation);
cvReleaseMat(&rot);
```

Now the error is that too few arguments to the function `cvWarpAffine`  and I really do not know why because  I have gone through so many examples and learn from them. Please, can someone help me?

Comment: `sizeof(frame)` will give you the size of the pointer to a `CvArr` (I assume). That is unlike what you want.

Comment: Could you extend (and reduce, i.e. remove unrelated stuff) your code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And then give the complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) is the right reference, then it looks like you are mixing the C and C++ interfaces.

The doc gives the following C-like interface:

```
C: void cvWarpAffine(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, const CvMat* map_matrix,
                     int flags=CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS,
                     CvScalar fillval=cvScalarAll(0) )
```

In which case you don't need the size, but I don't see why the size doesn't get converted to the flags.

Comment: Paramters `flags` and `fillval` are optional parameters (they default to `CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS` and `cvScalarAll(0)`)

Comment: The question is tagged C++, and openCV provides default arguments even to the C-API, if they are called from C++ code (using a macro `CV_DEFAULT`)